# How can I get my image?

Tags: html, css, image, iis, src

In a .js file I have, I am adding an image (this is for the image to go with select2).

My webapp is at `//myserver/apps/me/myapp/`.

My image is at `//myserver/apps/me/myapp/Content/image.png`.

`myapp` is the name of the folder my application lives in and I don't want to have to hard code it into my code.

I've tried the following sources:

- `~/Content/image.png` => `//myserver/apps/me/~/Content/image.png` (html doesn't recognize ~ as meaning anything it seems.)
- `./Content/image.png` => `//myserver/apps/me/Content/image.png`
- `/Content/image.png` => `//myserver/Content/image.png`
- `../Content/image.png` => `//myserver/apps/Content/image.png`
- `Content/image.png` => `//myserver/apps/me/Content/image.png`

It really seems like I'll have to hard code the app name (or get it in my layout while on the server side, store it into a javascript variable, and then use that variable to get the correct path.

Is there anything I can put in the src to get the actual path I need without having to hardcode or server side lookup `myapp`?  Or is there possibly a setup issue on IIS with my webapp causing this?

Server is IIS 7 (I think) If that matters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

since the image is not above or in a directory branched from above you should be able to access it just using a relative path "Content/image.png" using / infers root directory ./ is parent ../ is parent parent etc.

Comment: That gives `//myserver/apps/me/Content/image.png`.

Comment: I'm qioting you: `myapp is the name of the folder my application lives in and I don't want to have to hard code it into my code.`. In that case, `scr="Content/image.png"` wil give `//myserver/apps/me/myapp/Content/image.png`

Comment: if the paths you provided are in fact correct that should have worked just fine.

Comment: Your suggestion works in IE 11 and Firefox, but not in Chrome.  I'll dig into it but this may be more of a Chrome issue of not interpreting the paths correctly.

Comment: Actually, if I use //myserver/apps/me/myapp to get to my app in chrome, it doesn't work.  But if I use //myserver/apps/me/myapp/, it does load the image.  Seems the issues isn't the src attribute.  Actually, it appears all browsers are working that way.

Comment: Adding `<base href="~/" />` makes the application work the same with or without the /, in case anyone is encountering this issue.